# Automated Word VBA MailMerge

Tags: vba, ms-word, mailmerge

I was looking at the possibility of having a Word Mailmerge file that on opening the file a dialog box opens for the data source (excel file with different names).  It doesnt have to be mailmerge.... i am beating my head against wall every way I have tried fails...

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Document_Open macro like:

```
Private Sub Document_Open()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim StrMMSrc As String
With Application.FileDialog(FileDialogType:=msoFileDialogFilePicker)
  .Title = "Data Source Selector"
  .AllowMultiSelect = False
  .Filters.Add "Documents", "*.xls; *.xlsx; *.xlsm", 1
  .InitialFileName = ""
  If .Show = -1 Then
    StrMMSrc = .SelectedItems(1)
  Else
    GoTo ErrExit
  End If
End With
With ActiveDocument.MailMerge
  .OpenDataSource Name:=StrMMSrc, ReadOnly:=True, AddToRecentFiles:=False, _
    LinkToSource:=False, Connection:="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;User ID=Admin;" & _
    "Data Source=StrMMSrc;Mode=Read;Extended Properties=""HDR=YES;IMEX=1"";", _
    SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM `Sheet1$`"
End With
ErrExit:
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you..... That did what I was looking for thank you.....