# Automated MailMerge to Select Source File

Tags: vba, ms-word, mailmerge

I created a Word (2022) mailmerge document. I changed the .docx to a .docm so to do post-mailmerge processing on the generated output.

I'd like to allow selection of the source data file.

I found [Automated Word VBA MailMerge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61547489/automated-word-vba-mailmerge), which describes what I'm looking to perform. In my mailmerge document I now have:

```vb
Private Sub Document_Open()
'    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim StrMMSrc As String
    With Application.FileDialog(FileDialogType:=msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        .Title = "Data Source Selector"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Filters.Add "Documents", "*.xls; *.xlsx; *.xlsm", 1
        .InitialFileName = ""
        If .Show = -1 Then
            StrMMSrc = .SelectedItems(1)
        Else
            GoTo ErrExit
        End If
    End With
    With ActiveDocument.MailMerge
        .OpenDataSource Name:=StrMMSrc, ReadOnly:=True, AddToRecentFiles:=False, _
          LinkToSource:=False, Connection:="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;User ID=Admin;" & _
          "Data Source=StrMMSrc;Mode=Read;Extended Properties=""HDR=YES;IMEX=1"";", _
          SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM 'Students'"
    End With
ErrExit:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

When I open the merge document I can step through the Document_Open code. The FileDialog works, showing me the folder C:\Gld\RT\Office Database, and I select file "Database 2022-23.xlsx". Variable StrMMSrc is set to the file I selected, "C:\Gld\RT\Office Database\RT Database 2022-23 Test.xlsx". But then it pops up a window "Select Table" showing no tables. If I drop down Workbook, it shows me 2 old Excel documents and a document named "C:\Gld\RT\Office Database.xls", which doesn't exist.

Why is it confusing the "Office Database" folder with a non-existent "Office Database.xls" document?

Comment: I suggest in the first instance you remove all the parameters from the OpenDataSource call except Name and try again. Word should not need the Connection parameter for an OLEDB connection to Excel. If that works, put back the SQLStatement parameter. At the moment you are getting the ODBC dialog, BTW. There is a problem with your connection parameter which should have ..."Data Source=" & StrMMSrc & ";Mode=Read... but if you can omit the whole thing, so much the better.

Comment: the reason you get the ODBC dialog is usually because Word tried to open using OLEDB using any connection info provided and failed. Could be the problem I mentioned, the wrong provider name for the file type you are opening (actually probably OK in this case) or something about the .xlsx itself, e.g. OpenDataSource can't open a password protected file using OLEDB/ODBC.

Comment: Thanks, jonsson. Including just the Name fixed the problem. One further question: It now always prompts me for the Excel sheet name. If I add SQLStatement back to the .OpenDataSource, it goes back to failing as described previously. Is there some way for me to specify the Excel sheet name and column sort order, so my users don't have to deal with that?

Comment: The SQL syntax (Jet/ACE syntax) is wrong. Word uses backticks rather than straight quotes, e.g. SELECT * FROM `Students` rather than SELECT * FROM 'Students'. Or you can use square brackets SELECT * FROM [Students]. If Students is the name of a Sheet, you have to append a "$"  - SELECT * FROM [Students$]. If it's a range name, don't use a $. Word will generate an ORDER BY clause with ASC (the default) and DESC for sorting, e.g. SELECT * FROM [Students$] ORDER BY field1 ASC, field3 DESC. Or you can use the column numbers SELECT * FROM [Students$] ORDER BY 1 ASC, 3 DESC.

Comment: I see the backticks have been converted into shading. I mean SELECT * FROM \`Students\` .

Comment: Thanks once again. I had already changed my SELECT statement to begin with SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM [Students$]", and that worked fine. But I can't figure out the syntax for Order By clause, because two of my Excel columns have a space in their names. When the statement reads SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM [Students$] Order by [Grade] ASC, [Last Name] ASC, [First Name] ASC" or "... Order by [Grade] ASC, [""Last Name""] ASC, [""First Name""] ASC", it gives me the ODBC dialog again. Same for underscores in the two field names. I'm out of ideas...

Comment: JUst using [] as in your first example SELECT * FROM [Students$] Order by [Grade] ASC, [Last Name] ASC, [First Name] ASC should be OK (i.e. works OK here), assuming the names and spacing are correct (e.g. I suppose I would check that no column name actually has two spaces rather one in the Excel sheet). You can drop the ASCs as ASC is the default. Does the ORDER BY 1,2,3 style syntax work?

Answer (score 0):

Jonsson's comments answer the question accurately.

I don't know what went wrong the other day, but using the syntax
`SELECT * FROM [Students$] Order by [Grade] ASC, [Last Name] ASC, [First Name] ASC`
worked correctly today.

Thanks so much, Jonsson, for your time and effort in helping me.